# Как выровнять кнопку по одной линии с полем?

Tags: html, css

Код формы:

```css
div {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#block-search {
  float: right;
  margin: 7px 10px;
}

#block-search input[type="text"] {
  background: #f4f4ec;
  border: #dfdfdf 1px solid;
}

#block-search input[type="submit"] {
  background: #ce3c00;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border: #ba4f23 1px solid;
  height: 21px;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-search">
  <form>
    Search:
    <input type="text" size="10">
    <input type="submit" value="search">
  </form>
</div>
```

Вот так это выглядит сейчас:[image: кнопка]

Мне нужно, чтобы кнопка раполагалась на одной линии с полем ввода. Пробовал различные комбинации `margin` и `padding`, ничего не получилось. Если использовать флексы, то теряются все горизонтальные отступы между элементами.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сброс стандартных отступов и втяжек + выравнивание по вертикали

```css
div {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

#block-search {
  /*float: right;*/
  margin: 7px 10px;
}
  
#block-search form{
  vertical-align:middle;
}

#block-search input[type="text"] {
  background: #f4f4ec;
  border: #dfdfdf 1px solid;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
}

#block-search input[type="submit"] {
  background: #ce3c00;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
  border: #ba4f23 1px solid;
  height: 21px;
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  display:inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="block-search">
  <form>
    Search:
    <input type="text" size="10">
    <input type="submit" value="search">
  </form>
</div>
```